# Spice convergence troubles on this soft-start relay circuit simulation

Tags: ltspice, spice, capacitor-charging

I'm experimenting with a soft-start relay simulation. The relay is triggered when the capacitor bank C2 is charged a certain amount shorting R4. I then simulate loading V_out with a sequence of pulsing v_out to ground via a small ohmic load.

Simulation as shown converges, but tweaking the values of C1 or C2 less than one order of magnitude results in convergence issues. Is there an obvious newbie mistake visible to anyone in the screenshot?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try adjusting simulation parameters. The only culprits in here are likely the switches, which change very abruptly --> derivative diverges with timestep --> cannot continue numerical integration.

Comment: A few things to improve.  (1) Select an actual part# for the NPN.  (2) Your diode model has several issues.  Do not set the ON resistance to zero.  Set it to something like `1` or `1m` and also set the OFF resistance to a value like you did in your switch model statements. Also use the `epsilon` parameter (look it up in the LTspice help).  (3) Your switch models should set the `Vh` parameter to something negative (see the LTspice help section on this to see why).

Comment: Is "\$\mu\$" a valid character for a capacitor value in LTspice?

Comment: @Andyaka  It is.  When you enter in `u`, LTspice auto-converts it to a `µ` (presumably for aesthetics?).  There's a setting you can enable to tell it not to do this, but it's disabled by default.

Comment: @SteKulov That seems to have done the trick. In particular setting a very small hysteresis on the switches seems to have stabilised things. Add that comment as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your circuit that can cause convergence problems.  All of these can also apply to any SPICE circuit in general:

1. The default model for the NPN transistor is being used.  This implies that all terminal resistances and junction capacitances are zero.  These small components actually aid in convergence by adding bandlimiting RC circuits which can curb erratic behavior.  To alleviate this in LTspice, <kbd>rightclick</kbd> the transistor and select a pre-defined model from the list that best fits your application.
2. The standard [voltage-controlled switch](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/S_Voltage_Controlled_Switch.htm) model results in an abrupt change between the ON & OFF resistances when the threshold is crossed.  To help alleviate this, LTspice includes a modified switch model which smooths this transition between the two conduction regions.  To use it, you set the hysteresis parameter `Vh` to a negative value.  The magnitude of this value is the width of the smooth region, so try to go as wide as you can without affecting circuit operation.
3. You're using the [simplified piece-wise linear diode](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm) model, which is actually implemented very similarly to the above switch model.  Therefore, many of the same things apply.  By setting `Ron` to zero you're creating a giant chasm between `Ron` and `Roff` (default is 1 teraohm).  For proper operation you should first **never** use zero, and then also define a value for `Roff` similar to how you did in your switch `.model` statements.  The chasm between the two should never be bigger than 1/GMIN (GMIN default = `1e-12`).  So something like `Ron=1m Roff=1g` would be an example of the max you should go.  The simplified diode model also has the ability to offer a smooth transistion region by setting the `Epsilon` parameter which is similar to the `Vh` parameter above (except always positive).